# Random double in loop stays constant

Tags: c, random

I have the following c-program to generate random numbers in a loop. 
While this works well for integers, when I try to generate a random double between 0 and 1, the value stays constant throughout the loop.

- Why does that happen?
- How can I generate a random double in [0, 1] within a loop?

Source:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", rand()); 
    }
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", (double) rand() / RAND_MAX); 
    }
}
```

Output:

```
>gcc -O3 -o test test.c -lm 
>./test
787380606
1210256636
1002592740
1410731589
737199770
-684428956
-684428956
-684428956
-684428956
-684428956
```

Comment: the *format specifier* for `printf()` is not right.

Comment: and besides: what is the result of rand() / RAND_MAX?

Comment: @dbran0 shouldn't that normalize the random number between 0 and 1? Correct me, if I'm wrong

Comment: gregor: my bad. The cast has precendence over division, so it's ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behaviour of your code is undefined.

`(double) rand() / RAND_MAX` is an expression of type `double`. That requires a `%f` format specifier in your `printf` call.

(Also note that `(double) rand() / RAND_MAX` can draw `1.0` which is idiosyncratic. Normally you write `RAND_MAX + 1` on the denominator.)

Comment: rather `RAND_MAX + 1`? otherwise it could even be >1

Comment: @GregorSturm: Indeed, we'll publish jointly!